# Обращение к двухмерному массиву из ассемблера в Delphi

Tags: delphi, массивы, ассемблер, inline

```
TArr=Class(TObject)
    Constructor Create(Size: Integer); //Там мы всё создаём и инициализируем
  Private
    FArr: Array Of Array Of Byte; //Имеем двухмерный динамический массив (Соответственно все строки его будут разбросаны по памяти и передаваться как указатели...)
    Function getBit(Row, Col: Integer): Boolean;
    Procedure setBit(Row, Col: Integer; Value: Boolean);
  Public
    Property Bit[Row, Col: Integer]: Boolean Read getBit Write setBit; Default;
End;
```

Имеем функцию доступа к одному биту массива:

```
Function TArr.getBit(Row, Col: Integer): Boolean; Register; Assembler;
Asm           //EAX, EDX, ECX
  push ecx
  shr ecx, 3 //Col div 8, чтобы выбрать нужный байт
  mov edx, Self.FArr[edx]
  mov edx, [edx+ecx]
  mov dl, [edx]

  pop ecx
  mov eax, 7 //Col mod 8
  xor ecx, eax //8-position, т.к. нумерация бит с другой стороны
  and ax, cx
  bt dx, ax
  setc al
  sbb eax, eax
  neg eax
End;
```

Которая не работает(

Вот её рабочий аналог без ассемблера, чтобы было понятнее, что требуется:

```
Function TArr.getBit(Row, Col: Integer): Boolean;
Var
  nCol: Word;
  bPos: Byte;
Begin
  nCol:=Col Shr 3
  bPos:=Col And (FBitrate-1) Xor (FBitrate-1); //FBitrate=8
  Result:=(FArr[Row, nCol] And FMasks[bPos])<>0; //FMasks массив масок под каждый бит, чтобы не сдвигать каждый раз... Показалось так быстрее, но тоже лишняя работа с памятью.
End;
```

1. Почему параметры Row и Col передаются через EDX, ECX, если везде написано, что первые 3 параметра должны передаваться через EAX, EDX, ECX? EAX резервируется сразу под Result?
2. Когда Row=0 работает, иначе начинаются сюрпризы... Как правильно обращаться к динамическим массивам?
3. И хотелось бы её по скорости заодно оптимизировать, чтобы не трогать лишние регистры и, возможно, без BT будет быстрее и Mod и Div можно сразу получить одним делением, будет ли это быстрее?
4. Как изменится код при компиляции под x64?

ps: ах да, это всё в классе, поправил

Comment: 1. Вы про указатель this (он же Self) не забыли?

2. Почему Row 0? По жизни в Дельфи индексы шли с 1 (это не Си). Либо я в не курсе.

4. Никак. Или Вы хотите полностью его переделать, чтобы получить ускорение? Тогда как минимум задействовать 64-битные регистры, перекомпилировать программу целиком под 64 бита и пр.

Comment: @gecube, [2] шутить изволите? [4] там передача параметров через другие регистры, как минимум. А получится ли ускорение, переделав под x64, обращаемся же к байту?

Comment: @gecube, [2] с 1 - только строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему параметры Row и Col передаются через EDX, ECX, если везде написано, что первые 3 параметра должны передаваться через EAX, EDX, ECX? EAX резервируется сразу под Result?

В методах класса первый параметр всегда Self -> EAX.

> Когда Row=0 работает, иначе начинаются сюрпризы... Как правильно
>   обращаться к динамическим массивам?

Динамический массив (как и строка) - это , по факту, указатель на первый элемент массива. Причём, если массив имеет длину 0, то указатель содержит значение nil (0).
Вот вам работающий (у меня на Delphi 7) пример, как получить значение бита из двумерного динамического массива:

```
program arrtst;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

type
  TBitArray = class
  private
    FBits: array of array of Byte;
  public
    constructor Create;
    function getBit(Row, NBit: Integer): Boolean;
  end;

var
  Arr: TBitArray;

{ TBitArray }

constructor TBitArray.Create;
begin
  SetLength(FBits, 8, 4);  // пусть будет 8 рядов по 32 бита
  FBits[3, 2] := 182;      // 3й ряд = 00000000 10110110 00000000 00000000
end;

function TBitArray.getBit(Row, NBit: Integer): Boolean;
asm
  {
    на входе:
      EAX - Self
      EDX - Row
      ECX - NBit (0 ... 31)
  }

  // ассемблерные процедуры всегда должны сохранять значения регистров ebx, esi, edi, ebp и esp
  push  esi

  // в ассемблерных методах eax = self и наоборот, поэтому не обращайтесь к self,
  // если вы изменили значение eax и помните, что вызов любой функции, написанной
  // не вами, меняет его значение, соответственно указатель на self становится не
  // корректным
  mov   esi, eax.FBits // esi -> адрес первого элемента (строки) в FBits, т.е. FBits[0]

  // копируем NBit в eax, с этого момента Self вам больше недоступно!
  mov   eax, ecx

  // получаем адрес нужной строки: т.к. FBits - динамический массив из динамических
  // массивов, а динамический массив - это адрес указателя на первый элемент, то:
  mov   esi, [esi + edx * 4]  // 4 -> SizeOf(Pointer) (для 32 битного кода)

  // теперь получаем индекс нужного нам байта
  shr   eax, 3    // eax = NBit div 8

  // получаем порядковый номер бита в байте
  and   ecx, $07  // ecx = NBit mod 8

  // получаем значение нужного элемента, тут всё просто, но не забываем учесть размер
  // элементов второго массива (в данном случае SizeOf(Byte) = 1).
  movzx eax, byte ptr [esi + eax]

  // приводим результат к Boolean, где False = 0, True = 1
  shr   al, cl
  and   al, $01

  // и не забываем восстановить значения регистров, если мы их изменяли
  pop   esi
end;

var
  CCP: Cardinal;
begin
  CCP := GetConsoleOutputCP;
  Arr := TBitArray.Create;
  try
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    WriteLn(Format('Значение элемента через индекс:    %.2x %.2x %.2x %.2x',
      [Arr.FBits[3, 3], Arr.FBits[3, 2], Arr.FBits[3, 1], Arr.FBits[3, 0]]));
    WriteLn('Значение бита номер 23 в строке 3: ', Arr.getBit(3, 23));
  finally
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CCP);
    Arr.Free;
    ReadLn;
  end;
end.
```

> И хотелось бы её по скорости заодно оптимизировать, чтобы не трогать
>   лишние регистры и, возможно, без BT будет быстрее и Mod и Div можно
>   сразу получить одним делением, будет ли это быстрее?

Оптимизация по скорости - это отдельная тема для немаленькой статьи, если интересно - поищите в интернете, начать можно [вот отсюда](http://mark.masmcode.com/). Но имейте в виду, что на современных процессорах некоторые советы оттуда уже устарели.

> Как изменится код при компиляции под x64?

Изменятся используемые регистры, плюс SizeOf(Pointer) там не 4, а 8. Но так как я не писал на ассемблере под x64, то могу только посоветовать почитать справку от Delphi на это тему.

P.S: С точки зрения оптимизации по скорости, если вам не нужно хранить более 64 бит в строке, то я бы использовал одномерный массив Int64, например. Т.к. это будет на одно обращение к памяти меньше, при вызове данной функции.

Comment: "в ассемблерных методах eax = self, поэтому не обращайтесь к self, если вы изменили значение eax"
вот этого я не знал и нигде не мог найти объяснения, теперь всё на свои места встаёт... За ссылку отдельное спасибо, по немногу подшлифую теперь. Я сначала по этой ссылке теорию читал: http://www.kansoftware.ru/?tid=5097

PS: будет более конечно иначе бы не было смысла делить побайтно. Будет примерно до 90.000 бит в строке

Comment: @Isaev, не забудьте, что это всего-лишь пример. Там нет контроля индексов, нет обработки ошибок и т.п.

Comment: я же вижу, спасибо) мне надо было пару строчек из него... Главное принцип понять. и биты у меня с другой стороны считаются, но это всё мелочи

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю использовать стандартный `TBits` (одномерный булевый массив), вместо `Array Of Array Of Byte` и в функциях `getBit`/`setBit` просто пересчитывать `Row` и `Col` в индекс (пример для `getBit`):

```
VIndex := FWidth * Row + Col;
Result := FArr[VIndex];
```

где `FWidth` задаётся в конструкторе:

```
constructor TArr.Create(AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  FArr := TBits.Create;
  FArr.Size := AWidth * AHeight;
  FWidth := AWidth;
  FHeight := AHeight; // не обязательно
  ...
```

Т.е. стандартная задача замапить многомерный массив в одномерный.

Написать же свою реализацию `TBits`, да ещё и для `x64`, да ещё без багов и более быструю чем стандартная, может вот так просто не получиться.

P.S. Как вариант, можно взять себе код TBits и слегка подправить там обращение к нужному индексу, но я бы не рекомендовал так делать. Потому как это чревато багами, нужно делать лишнюю работу, а вот существенного профита в быстродействии может и не оказаться.

Comment: Про TBits не знал, спасибо... Но я всё равно намерен создать это колесо (оно в общем уже создано, просто узкие места оптимизировать решил), т.к. пришлось отказаться от одномерного ибо для решения матриц понадобилась частая перестановка рядов(узкое место)... В двухмерном это очень сократило время простой обменой указателей, в одномерном приходилось менять местами куски памяти.

Comment: О, если нужна перестановка рядов, то это многое меняет. Тут тогда может подойти `FArr: array of TBits;` если нужно переставлять только строки или столбцы. Если же нужно переставлять и строки и столбцы, то всё сильно сложнее.

Comment: нет, столбцы не нужно. я посмотрел имплементацию TBits:

 { Generate the mask }
  LMask := (1 shl (Index mod BitsPerInt));
  Result := (LRelInt^ and LMask) <> 0;

там так же при каждом обращении создаётся маска сдвигами, я так же сначала делал, это было очень медленно! И так же проверка через BT, везде пишут, что она медленная в большинстве случаев

Comment: По-умолчанию, там используется ассемблерный код, а не паскалевский. А говорить, что `BT` это медленно, можно только при наличии рабочего кода без `BT`, который выполняется быстрее. А пока у вас такого кода нету, то, как говорится, имеем что имеем.

Comment: У меня его и не будет и не будет возможности сравнивать, пока я не сделаю сам и не перестану пользоваться готовым) Оно хорошо, когда быстродействие не важно, но иногда нужно сделать своё, заточенное под определённые нужды. В ассемблере, который там выполняется не по-умолчанию, а если у нас CPUx64 первые строки проверка на ошибку размерности, это конечно хорошо, но оно кушает время и тут излишне.

Напишите как правильно обращаться из BASM к элементам двухмерного динамического массива, если знаете. Это будет намного полезнее для меня, в сети не смог найти этой информации.